# Remove and insert count of duplicates elements in a multidimensional array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have set of multidimensional array of borrowed books

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bid] => 1
            [begindate] => 2015-02-03 
            [title] => programming
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [bid] => 1
        [begindate] => 2015-02-03
        [title] => programming
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [bid] => 1
        [begindate] => 2015-02-03
        [title] => programming
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [bid] => 4
        [begindate] => 2015-02-03
        [title] => english
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [bid] => 4
        [begindate] => 2015-02-04
        [title] => english
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [bid] => 4
        [begindate] => 2015-02-04
        [title] => english
    )
```

)

I already have the code which removes the duplicate

```
0: begindate: "2015-02-03", bid: "1",title: "programming"    
3: begindate: "2015-02-03", bid: "4", title: "english"    
4: begindate: "2015-02-04"bid: "4"title: "english"
```

What i want is to insert the count of duplicates in that array so i can have a result like this...

```
0: begindate: "2015-02-03", bid: "1",title: "programming", count:"3"    
3: begindate: "2015-02-03", bid: "4", title: "english", count:"1"    
4: begindate: "2015-02-04", bid: "4", title: "english", count:"2"
```

Comment: just use a container which holds the count, increment every occurrence of a dup

Comment: What's your deduplication code? If you're simply using an indexed array for that, it's easy: just increment `count` every time you encounter a duplicate.

Comment: paste your code which removes the duplicate.

Comment: i just do this code sir $data = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data)));

Comment: the duplication should based on the begindate and bid. Sorry im just a beginner in handling multidimensional array

Comment: print_r your borrowed books array, that isn't valid php

Comment: the above array sir is the borrowed books array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty but this will do what you want:

```
//main array here is $books
$clean = array();
foreach($books as $k1=>$v1){
    $exists = false;
    //does an entry already exist in $clean?
    foreach($clean as $k2=>$v2){
        if($v1["begindate"]==$v2["begindate"]&&$v1["bid"]==$v2["bid"]&&$v1["title"]==$v2["title"]){
            $exists = $k2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($exists===false){
        //begin count, insert
        $v1["count"] = 1;
        array_push($clean,$v1);
    }else{
        //increment count
        $clean[$exists]["count"]++;
    }
}
print_r($clean);
```